# How to find a sequence of positions of a moving object in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an object (a point in a line) that is initially at position `x_min = 0`. At each time `d_t`, the object moves `d_t` units according to this set of values `d_t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`. So, after the first time, the object will be at position `x1 = 0 + d_1 = 1`. After the second time, the object will be at position `x2 = x1 + d_2 = 3`. After the third time, the object will be at position `x3 = x2 + 3 = 6`. After the fourth time, the object will be at position `x4 = x3 + 4 = 10`. After the fifth time, the object will be at position `x5 = x4 + 5 = 15` and after the sixth time, the object will be at position `x6 = x5 + 6 = 21`.

However, there is a limit of `x_max = 11`. So, the object cannot be in any position `x > x_max` or `x < x_min`. Thus, the position `x5` and `x6` must be corrected.

The object, before reaching `x5`, was at `x4 = 10` and will move `5` units in the next time. Since `x_max = 11`, the object can move further `1` unit and then must move backward `4` units. Hence, it will be at position `x5 = 10 + 1 - 4 = 7 < x_max`. Now, the object will move `6` units backward. Hence, `x6 = 7 - 6 = 1 > x_min`.

Finally, we get the sequence of position `0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 7, 1`.

I would like to write a Python code to find this sequence, given `x_max`, `x_min`, and the set `d_t`.

I was trying to do it and I start with this code but failed to continue.

```
x_min = 0
x_max = 11
x = x_min
for d_t in range(1, 7):
    if d_t + x <= x_max:
        x = x + d_t
    else:
        x = 2 * x_max - x - d_t
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: What's the issue? Seems straightforward enough?

Comment: Also, you use the terminology "set", i.e. "the set `d_t`", but you are working with a `range` object, which is quite different from a `set`. At least, keep in mind, that the word `set` in the context of Python usually refers to a specific data structure, coincidentally the one created by `d_t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, but this is *not* what you want to use.

Comment: The issue is that my code does not generate the correct sequence. It returns `1, 3, 6, 10, 7, 9`. Specifically, whenever I find out that I exceed `x_max` I go backward but only once. I have to go backward until `x_min` is reached and go forward again, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some way to keep track of which direction you're going in. In the code below, I use `sign` for that. When `sign` is +1 we go forward, when it's -1 we go backwards. When we go over `xmax` or below `xmin`, we need to reverse `sign`.

```
xmin, xmax = 0, 11
d_t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

x = xmin
sign = 1
for d in d_t:
    x += sign * d
    if x > xmax:
        x = 2 * xmax - x
        sign = -sign
    if x < xmin:
        x = 2 * xmin - x
        sign = -sign
    print(d, x)
```

**output**

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
5 7
6 1
7 6
8 8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator

def positions(xMin, xMax, dx):
    pos = xMin
    yield pos 

    ops = [operator.add, operator.sub]
    direction = 0 
    for d in dx: 
        pos = ops[direction](pos, d)
        if xMin <= pos <= xMax:
            yield pos 
            continue
        direction = (direction+1)%2
        pos = ops[direction]([xMin, xMax][pos>xMax], [xMin-pos, pos-xMax][pos>xMax])
        yield pos
```

Output:

```
>>> print(*positions(0, 11, [1,2,3,4,5,6]))
0 1 3 6 10 7 1
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter what the cube is move. Just think in different way and make it  easier to get.

```
d_t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
XX=[]
x_min = 0
x_max = 11
x = x_min
for d_t in range(1, 7):
        x += d_t
        XX.append(x)



LL=list(range(1,12))+sorted(list(range(1,11)), key=int, reverse=True)
[LL[i-1] for i in XX]


Out[17]: [1, 3, 6, 10, 7, 1]
```